# Would it be ok to mention in the post-doctoral application that my co-author is also applying for one of the two positions?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, application-cover-letter

I have been applying for some post-doctoral position in mathematics. Recently, I have came across two post-doctoral positions in the same department and in same research projects. On similar areas, I have worked with another person who is also a PhD student. We decided both to apply for the positions.
We have to send applications individually as it is.

> Should we mention in our cover letter that another applicant(co-author name) is also applying for the position and we can collaborate together if we get selected.

Is it bad Idea or good Idea?

I appreciate your advice.

Comment: It's hard to say and dependents on so many factors, honestly. I could see arguments going both ways. Can they infer from your previous collaborations that you already worked together?

Comment: Just a curiosity: why would you want to mention it? I don't see how it could benefit the CV in any way

Comment: @Pronte, since there are two positions in the same project, the hiring authority is probably looking for two persons who will work as a team. It might create a chance to select both of us, as we are already working on such topics as a team. This was intuition behind the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be OK, but there is no reason to do it. It will be obvious to anyone evaluating your application(s) with a glance at your CV.

Since such things are evaluated by individuals it is impossible to say what the effect would be so pretty hard to say good or bad idea. I think I'd rather not do this if it were me.

Of course, if asked, say that you are aware.

Comment: I agree with you. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it would be obvious for what the the question is mentioning as the reason. It could be obvious they have worked together in a lab, or both on a list of coauthors.  it doesn't mean they are explicitly excited or want to with together.